# Angular will not use templatecache

Tags: angularjs

Anguilar 1.5.*

I can not get angular to use my template cache. I gave it a invalid path name on purpose so I would get html file not found. But instead it is not using template cache and just requesting the html files.

templates.js

```
angular.module("gulpTemplates", []).run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) { $templateCache.put("aaaa/views/examples.html"
```

...

app.js

```
var gulpNewy =
  angular
  .module('gulpNewy', ['ngRoute', 'gulpTemplates'])
  .config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
      .when('/home', {
          templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
          controller: 'homeCtrl'
      })
      .when('/examples', {
          templateUrl: 'views/examples.html'
      })
      .when('/screen-shots', {
          templateUrl: 'views/screen-shots.html'
      })
```

index.html

```
<div class="col-xs-12" ng-view></div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you have / before aaaa when you use? or how do you use template?

Comment: Does gulpTemplates contain all content you need?

Comment: Is gulpTemplates module injecting properly?

Comment: Question doesn't make sense. If you provide invalid path of course a server request is made. Code showing what you put into cache is incomplete and nothing shown indicates where you call for template. Provide [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl `<div class="col-xs-12" ng-view></div>` indicates the call for the template. I provided the invalided path so the template should not show and complain about the path. You are incorrect, if it was using templateCache it would not request to the server for the html file but complain about the path.

Comment: Not by itself it doesn't without `$routeProvider.when()` defining the template

Comment: @charlietfl you should of realized  that to be correct, otherwise it would not be requesting to the server at all the html file. I stated in the original post it requests the html file. In any case, I updated the code with the `routeProvider`

Comment: Not at all clear what your problem is. Create a demo that replicates it

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the issue.

If you are using `ng-view`, `templateCache` will not work by default for you. This is because with `ng-view` you do not need to use `ng-include`. `templateCache` needs to be used with `ng-include` or `$templateCache.get`.

Regardless of `$templateCache.get`, `ng-view` will not look in templateCache.